# Backbone.js performing OPTIONS instead of POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, rest, backbone.js

I have a backbone client app and spring restful server.  The client side app is on localhost, the server side app is on localhost:8080.  If I have my model url set to localhost, it will run the POST (obviously failing).  If I have the url set to the correct localhost:8080, it runs OPTIONS instead.

I have implemented an OPTIONS controller, which answers the request.  I can see the API properly answering in both chrome's dev tools and wfetch.

But the POST never runs.

Here's the client code:

```
var cfd = function () { 
    var config = {
        serverURL: 'http://localhost:8080'
    };

    function init(authString) {
        var authHash = window.btoa(authString);

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Basic ' + authHash
            }
        });
    }

    var RegistrationModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: config.serverURL,
        defaults: {
            regFname: '',
            regLname: '',
            regHeardHow: 0
        }
    });

    var AuthModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: config.serverURL,
        defaults: {
            action: ''
        }
    });

    var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: config.serverURL + '/user',
        defaults: {
            email: '',
            fName: '',
            lName: '',
            heardHow: 0,
            isDeleted: 0
        }
    });

    return {
        AuthModel: AuthModel,
        RegistrationModel: RegistrationModel,
        UserModel: UserModel,
        config: config,
        init: init
    };
}();
```

And ...

```
var model;
cfd.init($('#email').val() + ':');

model = new cfd.UserModel({
    email: 'test@example.com',
    fName: 'Test',
    lName: 'Dude',
    heardHow: 21,
    isDeleted: 0
});

model.save();
```

Here's my API responding to OPTIONS:

```
RESPONSE: **************\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\n
Allow: POST,PUT,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS\r\n
Content-Length: 0\r\n
Date: Mon, 06 Jan 2014 16:30:31 GMT\r\n
\r\n
```

I have tried this with response code 200 and 204.

For completeness, here is my OPTIONS controller:

```
@Controller
public class OptionsController {

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setDispatchOptionsRequest(true);
        return servlet;
    }

    public static ResponseEntity<Void> allows(HttpMethod[] methods) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        Set<HttpMethod> allow = new HashSet<>();
        for(HttpMethod method: methods){
            allow.add(method);
        }
        headers.setAllow(allow);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
    ResponseEntity<Void> getProposalsOptions() {
        HttpMethod[] methods = new HttpMethod[5];
        methods[0] = HttpMethod.GET;
        methods[1] = HttpMethod.PUT;
        methods[2] = HttpMethod.POST;
        methods[3] = HttpMethod.DELETE;
        methods[4] = HttpMethod.OPTIONS;

        return allows(methods);
    }   
}
```

And the POST controller:

```
@Controller
public class PostController {

    @Inject
    private UserRepository users;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void insertUser(@RequestBody final User user) {
        users.save(user);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And why is Backbone doing a PUT in this case anyway?  Shouldn't it be creating a new one, POSTing?

Comment: Backbone will not run a PUT call when isNew() is true. Meaning that if there's an id set on the model, it will run a PUT, otherwise it will POST. 
0, BTW, will return false, therefore a POST call will be issued.

Comment: I updated the question to POST from PUT.  Same problem tho.

Comment: Are you certain that Backbone is doing an OPTIONS request and that problem isn't just some confusion server-side? Have you watched the request from your browser's dev tools? I don't think Backbone even knows what OPTIONS means.

Comment: @muistooshort Yup, when network logging is enabled this is appearing in the console:  OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/user.  The network view shows the same.

Comment: @muistooshort Maybe this is some behavior of .ajax ?  or .post ?

Comment: Perhaps due to the same origin policy

Comment: @muistooshort Maybe somehow I need to use jsonp?

Comment: First you need to figure who is sending that OPTIONS request and why they're doing it, I don't think Backbone will do that on its own. Your app is being loaded from `localhost:8080` right?

Comment: @muistooshort The webserver is localhost:80 and the app is on localhost:8080 ... it's just a dev environment, I haven't bothered setting up a reverse proxy to unify the url.  maybe I need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already hinted at by @Lurk21, your problem is a result of the browser-enforced [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FSame_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). By default, it forbids JavaScript code to make HTTP requests to a "origin" other than the one it is loaded from. As the port is part of the origin, `http://localhost` and `http://localhost:8080` are considered different origins, which causes problems.

However, a server might selectively allow requests from other origins by sending so-called [Crosss-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) headers with responses to `OPTIONS` requests. This is why you are seeing such requests in the browser developer tools. As your server's response doesn't include any CORS headers, the browser assumes that no cross-origin requests are allowed from this URL and aborts the request.

To resolve this problem, send headers such as the following with `OPTIONS` responses:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
```

Instead of `*`, you can also insert a specific origin you want to allow requests from. For additional headers you might need and other additional details, see the CORS documentation at MDN (linked to above).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the rule of 'same origin policy'.  Probably could have gotten around it with jsonp somehow, but I needed to reverse proxy in prod anyway, so I added it to my dev environment and it worked.